# Retrieving all European languages from CultureInfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

We are currently working on a webapplication in which people can specify their language. They should be able to choose a language from a dropdownlist, but including *all* languages supported by either Windows or .NET seems a bit overkill. I am trying to limit this to all European languages, but I can't seem to find a way without specifically specifying them in an array of strings.

Microsoft does not seem to have an implementation for this, does anyone have an idea of how to simply solve this issue?

Comment: I'd just go with the whole list - why, specifically, exclude people because their preferred language is Chinese, even though they currently live in Europe (and are, presumably, in the market for your software)?

Comment: it's ok to use array of strings as you mension. The is no such specific property that help you separate european languages only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start of with something like this:

```
    var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(
                x => x.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol == "€");
```

yet there will be missing some

Comment: I really like this solution. Very clever. Even though this does not include England, I can simply add the pound sign. Thanks alot!

Comment: @DionV. - there's more than one country in Europe that isn't part of the [Eurozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurozone). Just adding a £ doesn't cure that (in fact that article only covers Eurozone vs EU. There are plenty of countries which are wholly or partially in Europe which are in neither)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are correct, I wasn't aware of that. For now, I just leave the answer as is.